# Why does my debugger show different values than printed?

Tags: c++, debugging, glm-math

I have a class `FlyCommand` that looks something like this:

```
class FlyCommand : public Command
{
public:
    FlyCommand(float x, float y, float z) : dir(x, y, z, 0.0f) {}
    virtual void execute(SomeOtherClass& someOtherClassRef) 
    {
        std::cout << dir.x << dir.y << dir.z << std::endl; //pretend there's spaces in between
    }
    virtual ~FlyCommand(){}
private:
    glm::vec4 dir;
};
```

It inherits from `Command` which is simply an interface providing `execute(SomeOtherClass&)`. The type `glm::vec4` is a struct representing a mathematical vector with 4 float components (x,y,z,w), which is supposed to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary.

When I do the following:

```
int main()
{
    SomeOtherClass* s = new SomeOtherClass();
    FlyCommand* c = new FlyCommand(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    c->execute(*s);
    delete s;
    delete c;
}
```

Rather than printing out `1.0 2.0 3.0`, it spits out what appears to be junk, if constant junk, something like `0 -4.22017e+037 3.135e-017`. However, my debugger (MSVC 2013) shows the correct values for dir.x (1.0), dir.y (2.0), and dir.z (3.0).

I'm 99% sure that the issue with the junk being printed out is an alignment issue, as the GLM library provides a `#define GLM_FORCE_PURE` thingie that makes the values print out as they should, but disallows the use of SSE stuff on the vectors.

But I just want to know why the debugger shows different values than what is printed out. Shouldn't the debugger, uh, I don't know, "read" struct members the same way the compiler does? It doesn't make any sense for one thing to be alignment-independent and the other alignment-dependent, does it (I barely even know what that means)?

Comment: It would help if you can post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also it's not clear why you use `new/delete` in `main()` instead of just having variables.

Comment: Plus we would really like to see at least the constructor and members of `glm:vec4` together with whatever magic achieves the alleged 16-byte boundary alignment.

Comment: also: what happens if you use good old `printf()` instead of `cout <<` ?